# Dyniamic component within loop

Tags: angular

I know that in angular 2 we can create dynamic component using `ComponentFactoryResolver`. Here is my source http://blog.thecodecampus.de/angular-2-dynamically-render-components/.
We have to mark placement of new component with `#placement`

But I want to place it inside `*ngFor` In fact it is components with operations for table row:

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of data">
    <td>
        <div #operations></div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have two problems with it.

1. Angular populates only first `#operations`
2. How to pass argument (row index) to new component?

Comment: You can use a wrapper element like demonstrated in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468